# Nginx `proxy_ssl_trusted_certificate` with letsencrypt upstream

Tags: nginx, ssl, lets-encrypt, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm trying to use a `proxy_pass` with nginx where the connection to the upstream server is encrypted. The certificate of the upstream server has been created by a letsencrypt certbot.

```
# upstream server: nginx.conf

stream {
  server {
    listen 636 ssl;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/upstream.example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/upstream.example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot

    # ...
  }
}
```

When not verifying the proxy certificate in the downstream server, everything works fine.

```
# downstream server: nginx.conf

stream {
  server {
    listen 636 ssl;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/downstream.example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/downstream.example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot

    proxy_ssl on;
    proxy_ssl_verify off;

    proxy_pass upstream.example.com:636;

    # ...

  }
}
```

However, if I'm trying to verify the upstream certificate on the downstream server, I'm getting an **upstream SSL certificate verify error: (2:unable to get issuer certificate) while SSL handshaking to upstream** in the nginx error log.

```
# downstream server: nginx.conf

stream {
  server {
    listen 636 ssl;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/downstream.example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/downstream.example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot

    proxy_ssl on;
    proxy_ssl_verify on;
    proxy_ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/upstream.example.com/chain.pem;
    proxy_ssl_verify_depth 2;

    proxy_pass upstream.example.com:636;

    # ...

  }
}
```

Which settings for `proxy_ssl_trusted_certificate` and `proxy_ssl_verify_depth` do I need if the upstream server I'm trying to connect to has a letsencrypt certificate?

I've varied `proxy_ssl_verify_depth` from 0 to 5, and I've used the upstream server's `fullchain.pem`, `chain.pem`, and `cert.pem` for `proxy_ssl_trusted_certificate`, but each was unsuccessful.

#### Additional info

Verifying the CA certificate with `openssl` works:

```
# openssl verify -verify_depth 2 chain.pem
chain.pem: OK
```

Verifying the certificate from the upstream server, `fullchain.pem`, against the CA certificate works:

```
# openssl verify -CAfile chain.pem fullchain.pem
fullchain.pem: OK
```

#### Further references

- https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/securing-http-traffic-upstream/
- https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The CA certificate required for `proxy_ssl_trusted_certificate` is not provided by letsencrypt or the upstream server. It is already installed on the downstream server.

On Ubuntu, the location of the CA certificate(s) is `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt`.

```
# downstream server: nginx.conf

stream {
  server {
    listen 636 ssl;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/downstream.example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/downstream.example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot

    proxy_ssl on;
    proxy_ssl_verify on;
    proxy_ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt;

    proxy_pass upstream.example.com:636;

    # ...

  }
}
```

#### Documentation

https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html

> proxy_ssl_verify on | off;
>
> Enables or disables verification of the proxied HTTPS server certificate.
>
> proxy_ssl_verify_depth number;
>
> Sets the verification depth in the proxied HTTPS server certificates chain.
>
> proxy_ssl_trusted_certificate file;
>
> pecifies a file with trusted CA certificates in the PEM format used to verify the certificate of the proxied HTTPS server.

#### See also

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/484938/91720
- https://serverfault.com/a/1052976/167331